# Converting CSV files Into JSON while Changing the Key Names in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, csvtojson

I have 2 CSV files and I want to grab specific data (while ignoring some columns) from the CSVs and turn them into a JSON format with nested arrays and specific key names. I also want to order the JSON by a specific value (orderID).

Here's an example:

CSV file 1:

```
[ORDERIDENTIFIER, ORDERDTE, STORESTE, STOREADDRESS, STOREZIP, PRODUCTTYPE]
```

CSV File 2:

```
[ORDERTYPE, CUSTOMERAGE, CITY]
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "storeOrders": {
            "orderType": "2",
            "orderID": "22222",
            "orderDetails": {
                "productType": "Standard"
            },
            "collectedOrders": [
                {
                    "orderDate": "2023-09-03",
                    "customerAge": "22"
                }
            ],
            "storeDetails": {
                "storeState": "IA"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "storeOrders": {
            "orderType": "1",
            "orderID": "444",
            "orderDetails": {
                "productType": "Standard"
            },
            "collectedOrders": [
                {
                    "orderDate": "2023-06-03",
                    "customerAge": "60"
                }
            ],
            "storeDetails": {
                "storeState": "RI"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have tried using the csvtojson but am unsure how to use it for multiple files/changing key names`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper function to read and split csv to multidimensional array by newline and delimiter. Then use `map` to transform your data to the required array of objects structure. Pass custom function to `sort` to order by id.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readCsvFile = (fileName, delimiter) => fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8')
   .trim().split('\n').slice(1).map(row => row.split(delimiter));

const csv1Data = readCsvFile('csv1.csv', ','), csv2Data = readCsvFile('csv2.csv', ',');
const sortByID = (a, b) => parseInt(a.storeOrders.orderID) - parseInt(b.storeOrders.orderID);

const combinedData = csv1Data.map((row, i) => ({
    storeOrders: {
      orderType: csv2Data[i]?.[0],
      orderID: row[0],
      orderDetails: {productType: row[5]},
      collectedOrders: [ {orderDate: row[1], customerAge: csv2Data[i]?.[1]}],
      storeDetails: { storeState: row[2] }
    }
  }));
  

const sortedData = combinedData.sort(sortByID);

fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(sortedData, null, 2));
```